# Where to ask about firearms?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have questions about firearms, in particular about the functioning of a ["flintlock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flintlock), but really I'm a firearms fan and that takes me to many questions about all kinds of weapon styles.
I also have questions about [ICBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercontinental_ballistic_missile), and many more "war" related machines and apparatus. I think my questions are tecnical in nature and refer to how a machine works. So, should I ask them in [engineering stack exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Engineering Stack Exchange does indeed have a [firearms tag](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firearms). The suitability of your question really depends on what particular aspect of the weapon you're asking about. Three of the four are about the mechanisms of a firearm; the fourth is about a physical effect inside a gun. If your question is along those lines, I think Engineering would accept it.

If the question is unrelated to the engineering aspect of a firearm, I suspect it would be poorly received, and likely closed as off-topic.

There was once a [Firearms Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164/firearms), four years ago, but that closed due to a lack of activity.

[Space Exploration Stack Exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/) also has an [ICBM tag](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icbm), but I'm not quite as clear how ICBMs are in scope there.

Answer (score 11):

[The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has a ["guns"](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) tag with 10 non-closed questions, covering the use of firearms.

For larger-scale weapons, though, Outdoors wouldn't seem to fit. As mentioned already, [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might fit some ICBM-related questions. It's also worth noting that questions about the physics of explosions might fit [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).