# Where should I go to ask a question about guns?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I spend most of my time on the Writing Beta SE, because I'm a writer.  I have a question about how to refer to and explain gun mechanics in my novel, as I am not experienced with guns, but these types of questions usually are closed as asking "what to write".  Is there a weaponry SE, or another relevant SE to post this question to?

Comment: Related, don't know if dupe, don't want to plagiarize the answers: [Where to ask about firearms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286211/398063)

Comment: There is some information on the [WorldBuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns).

Comment: For people who are asking about firearm *laws*, the best fit might be the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some gun-related questions are on topic at [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns), particularly if you're asking in a hunting-related context.