# Where to ask about identification and clarification of military equipment?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

**The question aims to find a similar place to the ["identify-aircraft" tag in Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-identification) but for military equipment such as missiles. Whether this is from an active war or a past one doesn't matter, the question is more general.**

**As an example**: I have a video/picture that depicts a missile hitting a building and would like to find out what type of missile it could have been.

However, I do not know the right place to ask this question. A [similar meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286211/where-to-ask-about-firearms) points to Space Exploration with the ICBM tag, however, [posting it there with the cautious hint that I am glad about better suiting sites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58458/what-kind-of-missile-is-hitting-this-building) resulted in immediate closure as off-topic (and no suggestion on a better place).

I've seen this kind of question in the Aviation SE for airplanes, however this is about missiles and weapon systems.

This is not just about "seeing" a missile, but about logical factors involved (see also the link above), such as: from which angle is the object coming, why does it have a white trail, how large is the explosion radius?

---

**Actuality**: it was brought up in comments that during the conflict it may not be a good idea to discuss this. However, there are many SE threads that discuss very recent topics [such as why India abstained on the UNSC resolution on Russia and Ukraine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71099/why-has-india-abstained-on-the-unsc-resolution-on-russia-in-ukraine). I therefore see no problem in trying to ask questions on matters that are happening *right now*.

Comment: Why does this get downvoted so much? It's a perfectly suitable question for Meta. From the [Help] page: "Questions seeking to know which site on the network is the best match for a question or subject - use the site-recommendation tag" is mentioned under "Questions that are a good fit here". That ID questions are generally not allowed is something not everyone is familiar with.

Comment: I don't think anyone can determine with 100% accuracy the type of missile used, and with that the party responsible for launching it, without looking at the wreckage. So not much we keyboard heroes could do here. Nor would it change anything if you, a random person on the internet, knows what missile was fired. Is that going to punish the guilty party, or redeem the victims in some shape or form? I can understand your curiosity, but its better spent elsewhere.

Comment: @Joachim I would guess in general, people disagree with some aspect of the question. I chose to answer, and Luuklag makes some great points in his comment above.

Comment: @Luuklag I tried to better highlight the question. This is about _where in general_ can such questions be asked. Yes, maybe people are not able to identify this, but that is irrelevant, it's the same for the "identify-aircraft" tag. If that exists, why not for military equipment? And there is quite something we can do: the public opinion, based on many small incidents that are again based on pictures like the above, can have a large effect.

Comment: @Mayou36 I think the first sentence of my comment is pretty clear. But I can summarize it as: no-where.

Answer (score 6):

Well, identification questions are generally "not" a great fit — especially if the video is of them being fast moving objects that have come to a sudden, destructive stop inside a civilian building in the middle of an ongoing war.

ICBMs are on topic for space since, well, an ICBM is pretty much a suborbital launcher whose payload returns, and many ex-ICBMs were used either as a basis for, or as low cost launch vehicles with minimal modifications. It wasn't a general allowance for anything to do with rocketry I suspect.

In theory, once this... godawful mess is over this *might* be a fit for history — they do seem to do [identification questions](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=identify).

*Right now* though, it's precious little solace to the people who live there. I've been following a bit of discussion over this and *right now*, I'm fairly convinced that many mods wouldn't feel this is a good fit for their site. Topicality aside as I told someone else, it's a little too soon.

Comment: "especially if the video is of them being fast moving objects" I updated the question for clarification on the technicalities. "its a little too soon" - I think this is exactly the right moment, because the circumstances are debated and there is some video material around and arguments. Would you suggest that SE is not the right place to discuss this things? AviationExchange has a lot of these identify sites ([example question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91526/what-is-that-plane-flying-over-missouri-at-59-700-ft)) that are momentarily.

Comment: In terms of an ongoing war, where people are dying? I'm not sure I'm generally comfortable with the topic *personally* as would be many others.  There's a big difference between peacetime "what's that" and what's essentially a missile blowing up someone's home

Comment: Isn't in war, where misinformation is actively spread, the truth seeking in an all-accessible platform such as SE a need?

But irrespective of whether it is happening now or not, is the question of finding out what missile it was so bad? I am sorry that you do not feel comfortable with this topic but others don't have that choice.